# Keyboard shortcuts to buy items in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

In Counter Strike, for a quick start, one should buy items by using keyboard shortcuts at the beginning of the game, not clicking to items with mouse.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to buy items quickly in League of Legends? Or any plugins to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Never heard of shortcuts to buy items. Furthermore, I think that plugins are not legit for the game.

Comment: I know that there are some plugins that Riot OKed in the past, including on screen buttons to call MIA from various lanes. I doubt they would have a problem with you using a plugin simply to bind item purchases to keystroke sequences.

Comment: But you don't need to bind items... because simply put you might have a core build of 2 items, but the rest should be bought as you go depending on the enemy team. You can never get stuck with the same item build... even your starting item... sometimes you want to go with boots, or somethimes with a dorian's item... and so on... why bind them if they nearly always change?

Comment: The only hotkey/keyboard shortcut for the shop (that is built into the game) is "P" which opens the shop menu.

Comment: They are making item purchasing easier: http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/news/item-shop-and-game-hud-updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't any inbuild shortcuts in the game, but there is a program which allows you to change the recommended items into what you want them to be. It should make buying easier.

The program is called Enigma's Recommended Item Changer, and can be found here: http://enigmablade.net/eric/

Comment: At the moment you change your recommended items in game. (I know this is answered over a year ago, but since it came up on front page.)

Answer (score 5):

The only hotkey/keyboard shortcut for the shop (that is built into the game) is "P" which opens the shop menu.

As far as "plug-ins" are concerned, you might want to check out the [EULA](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/legal/eula)

> You agree that you will not, under any circumstances:
>   E. Use any unauthorized third-party programs that interact with the Software in any way, including but not limited to, “mods,” “hacks,” “cheats,” “scripts,” “bots,” “trainers,” or automation programs, or any third-party programs that intercept, emulate or redirect any communication between the Software and Riot Games, or that collect information about the Game by reading areas of memory used by the Software to store information about the Game.

Comment: Actually, if you look around on the forums, there are alot of Reds (Riot Employees) that talk about the custom skins over on Leaguecraft.com. For a while there, Brorelia was actually a sponsored skin. As far as I know, they have the same attitude towards mods that don't actually affect gameplay... So long as someone isn't trying to make a mod that reveals the entire map or anything, I think they don't mind.

Comment: Skins are one thing (graphical only) but you think that setting up a mod for the shop that makes the *interaction* different for you than for everyone else is not affecting gameplay? Besides, just because they let something slide doesn't mean it isn't against the EULA.